# IntelliJ 'Shelve Changes' equivalent feature in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, shelving

I am exploring VS-Code and I am used to the 'Shelve Changes' feature in IntelliJ.
I was wondering if there is an equivalent feature or if there is a way to store temporary changes in VS code.

Comment: Use `git stash`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent feature (or extension) available in VS Code.

As you know, IntelliJ Shelve and Git Stash are similar, but two different beasts (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-on-several-features-simultaneously.html), and if Git Stash itself doesn’t fit your needs, you are out of luck.

You will probably have to wait until someone develop a similar feature, or reverse engineeer (if legally possible / open) IntelliJ Shelve feature for compatibility reasons.

Hope this helps